# File contains two EOF characters; what happens?

Tags: unix, eof

Will this screw up file size estimation on the file system? Will the filesystem overwrite everything past the first EOF character? How is this handled?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405818/does-eof-actually-exist seems relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unix there is no EOF character. It's simply a concept, a value returned by `getc` to signal "this is the end (beautiful friend)". `EOF` is chosen so that `getc` (and friends) can't return it in any other case.

And about writing past the end of file, different filesystems do things differently.

- Some will leave holes that don't actually occupy any space on the disk
- Some will fill in the blanks with blanks (0)

Comment: I think he is talking about ^D characters (bytes with value 4) when reading in text mode.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Text mode is a MS braindamage. I think it's ^Z or `0x1A`. Someone explained to me where it comes from, I think it's CP/M.

Comment: I feel the need to note that getc returns an int and not a char! Many people new to getc forget this or don't know this and therefor, will enter an infinite loop.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel [See the comment of Michael Burr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586382/binary-output-in-windows/6586410#6586410)

Comment: Since ^Z corresponds to a byte with value 0x1A, and ^D is used on the standard input to indicate EOF in unix-like environments, I assumed that a byte with value 0x04 within a file 'in text mode' would be treated the same way... regardless of the lack of newline translation. :/

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Nice analogy, but no, Unix doesn't store that `^D`.